# Jackson combining @JsonIdentityInfo and @JsonTypeInfo throws InvalidTypeIdException

Tags: json, serialization, jackson, object-identity

Currently I am having an issue with Jackson when I combine `@JsonIdentityInfo` and `@JsonTypeInfo`. The Kotlin code below throws an exception on the last line. It serializes the `dog1AndDog1Json` instance as expected into Json but it then throws an exception while deserializing it back into an instance.

```
package some.test

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
@JsonSubTypes(JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog::class), JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat::class))
interface Animal {
    val name: String
}

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator::class)
data class Dog(@JsonProperty("name") override val name: String) : Animal

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator::class)
data class Cat(@JsonProperty("name") override val name: String) : Animal

data class TwoAnimals(@JsonProperty("animal1") val animal1: Animal, @JsonProperty("animal2") val animal2: Animal)

fun main() {
    val om = ObjectMapper();

    val dog1 = Dog("Dog1")
    val dog2 = Dog("Dog2")
    val cat1 = Cat("Cat1")

    val dog1AndDog2 = TwoAnimals(dog1, dog2)
    val dog1AndDog2Json = om.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(dog1AndDog2)
    assert(dog1AndDog2 === om.readValue(dog1AndDog2Json, TwoAnimals::class.java)) // OK

    val dog1AndCat1 = TwoAnimals(dog1, cat1)
    val dog1AndCat2Json = om.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(dog1AndCat1)
    assert(dog1AndCat1 === om.readValue(dog1AndCat2Json, TwoAnimals::class.java)) // OK

    val dog1AndDog1 = TwoAnimals(dog1, dog1)
    val dog1AndDog1Json = om.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(dog1AndDog1)
    println(dog1AndDog1Json)
    assert(dog1AndDog1 === om.readValue(dog1AndDog1Json, TwoAnimals::class.java)) // DESERIALIZE FAILS
}
```

Then I run the main function I get the following output:

```
{
  "animal1" : {
    "@class" : "some.test.Dog",
    "@id" : 1,
    "name" : "Dog1"
  },
  "animal2" : 1
}
```

Followed by this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class some.test.Animal]: missing type id property '@class' (for POJO property 'animal2')
 at [Source: (String)"{
  "animal1" : {
    "@class" : "some.test.Dog",
    "@id" : 1,
    "name" : "Dog1"
  },
  "animal2" : 1
}"; line: 7, column: 15] (through reference chain: some.test.TwoAnimals["animal2"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException.from(InvalidTypeIdException.java:43)
<truncated rest of stacktrace>
```

It seems that Jackson expects an object at the `animal2` property which has a @class property to find the correct class type to be deserialized. But it has been replaced with an id by the `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotation. Why does Jackson not look up the object by that id and then check the @class property of that instance?

I am not sure if this use case is not supported by Jackson or I am doing something wrong (what I am hoping for). Or maybe it is a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to to get it working by:

1. Removing the `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotation from the `Dog` and `Car` sub classes
2. Adding a `@JsonIdentityInfo` to the `Animal` base class